# Javascript to stop WordPress registration form submission (email validation)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation, email, registration

I have successfully integrated the mailrefine.io API with my WordPress registration form for email validation. Now, when a user fills in the form and clicks on submit, a message pops up and either says "Email valid" or "Email invalid" depending on the email validation results from the API connection.

The problem is, as soon as the message appears underneath the email input field, the form submits and redirects the user to another page regardless of the validation result.

I have written the javascript below to instead check the email validation result first and if it is invalid to stop the submission so the user can enter a valid email address.

```html
<script>
document.getElementById('wp-submit').onclick = function(){
if(document.getElementById('mailrefine-msg').innerHTML == 'Email is invalid'){
window.stop();
}
}
</script>
```

The above script is not working and the only thing I can find when I debug the code is that I might need to replace the onclick event in line 1 with something else?

Thank you for your help.

Below is my form's html code if it helps.

```html
<form name="registerform" id="mailrefine-form" action="https://alliedhealthprograms.com/login/?action=register" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <p>
            <label for="user_login">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" autocapitalize="off">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="user_email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" id="mailrefine-email" class="input" value="" size="25">
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" id="ct_checkjs_register_form_061412e4a03c02f9902576ec55ebbe77" name="ct_checkjs_register_form" value="1068643702"><script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){var ct_input_name = "ct_checkjs_register_form_061412e4a03c02f9902576ec55ebbe77";if (document.getElementById(ct_input_name) !== null) {var ct_input_value = document.getElementById(ct_input_name).value;document.getElementById(ct_input_name).value = document.getElementById(ct_input_name).value.replace(ct_input_value, '1068643702');}}, 1000);</script>      <p class="loginpress-reg-pass-wrap">
    <label for="loginpress-reg-pass">Password</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="loginpress-reg-pass" id="loginpress-reg-pass" class="input" size="20" value="" type="password">
  </p>
  <p class="loginpress-reg-pass-2-wrap">
    <label for="loginpress-reg-pass-2">Confirm Password</label>
    <input autocomplete="off" name="loginpress-reg-pass-2" id="loginpress-reg-pass-2" class="input" size="20" value="" type="password">
  </p>
            <p id="reg_passmail">
            Registration confirmation will be emailed to you.           </p>
        <br class="clear">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="">
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Register">
        </p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return false` at the end of your onclick event. That will stop the form submission.

```
<form id="myForm">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
      <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
window.onload = function () {
  const myForm = document.forms.myForm;
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.onclick = function () {
    const email = document.forms.value;

    // validate email
    
    // return false to stop submission
    return false;
  };
};
```

**Option 2**: you can use form submit event

```
window.onload = function () {
  const myForm = document.forms.myForm;
     myForm.onsubmit = function () {
       const email = myForm.email.value;
       // validate the email
       // return false to stop form submission
       return false;
   };
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/b4t69od1/1/

Comment: Hi @pallavdubey thank you for your reply. As you suggested, I tried replacing window.stop() with return false; in my code however this is not working. Would it help if I provided you with the registration page URL so you could investigate it yourself?

Comment: sure @kt3486, I can try. Also add your form HTML snippet to the question. It would help in understanding the question better.

Comment: Thank you, @pallavdubey as you suggested I have updated my question by adding my form's html code snippet a the bottom of my question. Also, feel free to investigate and test the form, here is a link to my registration page: https://alliedhealthprograms.com/login/?action=register

Comment: I just tried it out with your html. If you `return false` in your onclick event it will stop the form from submitting. May be your new JS was not updated in the browser. Try **clearing the cache or hard refresh `(ctrl + shift + R)`** and try it again.
here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/b4t69od1/1/.

Just tried on your registration page as well. It does not redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I viewed the page source code and the code that I added is displaying. Additionally, this page is excluded from my cache. I tried a hard refresh and that did not fix the issue either.